# Aws JSON Lambda function, 'date-holiday' package

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, date, aws-lambda

I am building an AWS Lambda function that emails the S3 location of call recordings to a mailbox if the office is out of hours. I can get it to send emails if any call is made but when I enter the conditions I fall down. I want the function to only operate on holidays and outside office hours(Christmas, bank holiday.....). I haven't tried weekends yet but I know how to go about doing that. I want to use the 'date-holidays' package but I am having trouble getting it to work. I can get the emails to send if it is not between 9 & 5 but I cannot get them to send if it is say Christmas day.

Or if there is an easier way, please suggest

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new aws.SES({
    region: 'us-west-2'
});
var time = new Date().getHours();
var td = new Date().getDate();
const s3 = new aws.S3({
    apiVersion: '2006-03-01'
});
if (time > 17 || time < 9){
    if (td == hd){

        exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
            console.log("Incoming: ", event);
            const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
            const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
            const now = new Date();
            const news = `Event took place in https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/object/${bucket}/${key}`;
            const params = {
                Bucket: bucket,
                Key: key,
            };

                var eParams = {
                    Destination: {
                        ToAddresses: ["***********.com"]
                    },
                    Message: {
                        Body: {
                            Text: {
                                Data: `${news}`

                            }

                        },
                        Subject: {
                            Data: `Voicemail notification for ${now}`
                        }
                    },
                    Source: "*************.com"
                };

            console.log('===SENDING EMAIL===');
            var email = ses.sendEmail(eParams, function(err, data) {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                else {
                    console.log("===EMAIL SENT===");
                    // console.log(data);
                    console.log("EMAIL CODE END");
                    console.log('EMAIL: ', email);
                    context.succeed(event);
                }

            });
        }
    }    
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what trouble you have it with 'date-holidays', you could try uploading node_modules folder also with Lambda and test (there is a data/holidays.json file)

var Holidays = require('date-holidays')
hd = new Holidays('US', 'la', 'no')

```
if(hd.isHoliday(--now--)) {

}
```

Comment: i uploaded the date-holidays JSON file with the lambda function and used the code your provided but this is the errro I got                                       {
  "errorMessage": "Holidays is not a constructor",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)"
  ]
}